# Can't retrieve data from sqlite3 file with unexpected characters

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, sqlite-browser

I have **sqlite3 database file** that I'm trying to get data from. When I try to open it in sqliteBrowser it will generate the tables but it ignores the data within the file so I get empty tables. This is the file: [localData.sqlite](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QUdzVdT0__nsVVjUBzQw_Kl5bEXDBShG/view?usp=sharing)

[image: sqliteBrowser view]

I don't know if the file is bad formatted or if I'm missing some function I have to run over it.

The file was created by a third party application on windows with the code below.

**File creation**

```
        {
            try
            {
                if (!File.Exists("queueData.sqlite"))
                {
                    SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("queueData.sqlite");
                }

                using (SQLiteConnection c = new SQLiteConnection(connection))
                {
                    c.Open();
                    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("create table if not exists vehicles (data TEXT)", c))
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("create table if not exists vehiclesMQTT (data TEXT)", c))
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("create table if not exists faces (data TEXT)", c))
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("create table if not exists facesMQTT (data TEXT)", c))
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    c.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                AdLogsManager.instance.writeErrorMessage("Creating DB and Table: " + ex.Message,"", "", 7001);
            }
        }
```

**Data insert**

```
        {
            try
            {
                var tableName = getTableNameByType(type);
                string sql = "insert into " + tableName + " (data) values (\'" + data + "\')";
                using (SQLiteConnection c = new SQLiteConnection(connection))
                {
                    c.Open();
                    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, c))
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    c.Close();
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                AdLogsManager.instance.writeErrorMessage("Saving data: " + ex.Message,"", "", 7002);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

If anyone could help me solve the issue or find a way to obtain the data, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: Your sqlite db is corrupted beyond recogntion - there are 4 empty tables there. No way to get anything useful. Look for backups.

Comment: I have no backups. The third party application stores data this way.. Is there a way I can add some extra instructions to the file or make a script to get the data from it?

Comment: I used tool [undark](https://github.com/witwall/undark) on your db, but really, your data is fubared

Comment: Yes, something in the app is damaging the records. Will continue checking. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With no warranties at all!

Your database is corrupt or, somehow, records were deleted.

However, you still can open your file in a text editor and see a lot of records like:

> ...`{"channel":"app-emit","payload":{"type":"vehicle","deviceId":"d4f9bb04b6d5","time":1595510864502,"appName":"vehicle","appVersion":"1.0.1","data":{"count":1,"speed":0.0,"zoneId":"inbound","time":1595510864502}}}`...

I don't know which table they belong or if they are actual or outdated, not even how many are lost.

Using this method, could recovered 4087 records: https://justpaste.it/38j03

Further knowledge on your application should help you evaluate if they are useful or not.

EDIT: Method used:

I used a hexadecimal/text editor (MadEdit) to:

1. place a break before `{"channel":` (replace hex 7B226368616E6E656C223A with **0A**7B226368616E6E656C223A)
2. place a break after `}}}` (replace hex 7D7D7D with 7D7D7D**0A**)
3. removed every occurrence of null (replace hex 00 with nothing)

Then copied everything an pasted into spreadsheet application (Excel), so some sorting and filtering may be done.

Better method: open in Word, make same replacements (`{"channel":` to `^p"channel":` and `}}}` to `}}}^p`), then paste to Excel.

Comment: Yes, I think something in the application is wring and is damaging the file.. But thank you! This is very helpful thank you! I need to do the same with several other files. Could you share with me the method and how you recovered this so I can repeat the procedure? Thank you again!